# В каком случае ставится ”,”?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Я хотела бы спросить, когда ставится ","?

Comment: Не совсем ясно, что именно вас интересует. Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Правила постановки запятой собраны тут.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/144-zap

Но их много, и ими надо уметь пользоваться. Этого всего в одном ответе не расскажешь.

Напишите пример, который вам непонятен.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Не тот случай, когда это возможно. Вопрос такой.